# Trying to run tomcat8 / rest api app combination in docker container - can't map ports

Tags: docker, tomcat, containers, ports

Good day. I have tomcat 8 and a rest api application I need to run in 4 or 5 containers, for testing of a client process.
I already have a tomcat 8 instance on my Windows 10 machine, it connects on port 8080, like tomcat normally does.
My container/image tomcat is also set for port 8080, so I can browse to the 'Default Switch' IP address and port 8080, and the tester interface comes up.

But with multiple docker instances need, I'm trying to run docker with:
'docker run -it -p 8081:8080  /bin/bash', so I can start and stop the container tomcat as needed.
From my research, using -p 8081:8080 should map the container tomcat port (8080), to my host port 8081, so I can use 'localhost:8081' to browse to the app deployed on the container tomcat.

When I run the above command with -p 8081:8080, I'm getting:

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint musing_thompson (771e81801b1e20512aff36f6ec25544ca34a03181b8bd3a251f13c3edb328690): Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:8081:tcp:172.17.0.2:8080: input/output error.

Is this the correct way to use '-p', or am I mixing up my hosts/ports ?

Comment: check this issue thread https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573

Comment: I *finally* figured out how docker sets up windows to utilize containers. It uses the "docker run -it -p 8081:8080 /bin/bash" command to map the 8081 port to windows, but it uses "Ethernet Adapter vEthernet (Default Switch) as the ip address of the container(s).  Browse to <that-ip-address>:8081/<app> to get access to the app. Use ipconfig in windows to see that adapter.

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing the same problem. so all i did is run this command `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` and restarted the docker. sometimes simply starting the docker also works fine. it worked for me.